# JavaScript function/object structure is unclear to me

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

So, I'm getting into JavaScript in order to get ready for some ClojureScript and React. I have checked through a number of descriptions, including

- [MDN Web Docs on JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/)
- The book *["JavaScript - The Good Parts"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do)* (which is a bit oldish, as it is about JavaScript 1.7/1.8 (prior to 2008))
- And several other web sources.

... and i'm still not sure how the Functions/Objects concepts are structured. I realize JavaScript does not have a "classical" type system like Java, but is practically [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29) with pointy `{}` syntax. Still...

There is some muddy use of words in the descriptions (we have *types* (huh?), *classes* (hmm...), *instances*, *inheritance*, *objects*, *prototypes*, *functions*, *constructors*, *methods*) ... all used disagreeably fluidly. There is even the occasional *kind* being bandied about, in a language that doesn't actually have first-order types.

Leaving aside actual JavaScript "classes", which are syntactially sugared objects with some extras, if I understand correctly:

- There are **objects** and there are **functions** which are instantiated into **instances**. (I am not sure what actually distinguishes objects and functions; is it the root of the instance tree?)
- The **object instances** (blue in the diagram) form a tree via the "prototype" relationship (which is "internal", thus hidden). The tree root is the instance [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).
- There is a **global object** [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), also known as *"the Object constructor"*. It has a visible "prototype" reference to (the not otherwise named object) [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) (also known as *the Object prototype object*).

  - I'm not sure whether the global object [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is indeed a function. It should be. Does it have a internal reference to the [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)?
- The **function instances** (green in the diagram) likewise form a tree via the "prototype" relationship. The tree root is the instance [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype).

  - But maybe they don't form a tree, just a one-level hierarchy. What would it mean for a function instance to have a prototype chain after all?
- There is a **global object** [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), also known as *"the Function constructor"*. It has a visible "prototype" reference to (the not otherwise named object) [Function.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) (also known as *the Function prototype object*).

  - If I interpret [this text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype) correctly, `Function.prototype` holds values like `Function.prototype.length` and `Function.prototype.name` that make sense only for specific functions. What gives? Do function instances shadow all the relevant values of `Function.protoype`?
- Every function instance references its creation **context** and its **code** (yellow)
- Finally a function instance apparently has an associated prototype via its "prototype" value. Conversely that instance refers back to the function instance via the "constructor" value. Not sure what that does.

[image: JavaScript object and function trees]

Barring extras like "classes", am I missing things. Is this completely wrong? What needs to be corrected?

Comment: So many questions in one post. You have to split at least.

Comment: If only I had a couple of hours to answer this question...

Answer (score 2):

Everything you talk about is an object: it has an identity (in the OOP sense) and it can be mutated. (The other kind of values next to objects are primitives which are immutable non-reference values).

An object has properties (key-value pairs, where the key is either a symbol or a string) and some internal machinery. Part of this machinery is its prototype link, accessible through `Object.getPrototypeOf`, pointing to an object or `null` from which the object can inherit properties.

Functions are objects with extended internal machinery that makes them callable. (Referencing code and context is part of that, but not really important here).

All these objects are not necessarily "instances" of anything, they can just be created as objects and they exist.

The objects do not form a tree. A prototype link references an object that has another prototype link and so on, forming a prototype chain. Sure, multiple objects inheriting from the same object form a tree-like structure, but unlike a tree the children reference their parents not the other way round. Also, there is no root node, any object can link `null` and not inherit from anything - so it's more like a forest at best.

That's about it what you need to know about an object's structure in JS. I'm not going to expand on constructor functions, their properties with the name `prototype`, and how they form class-like structures with "instances" through inheritance. You can find details on that pattern, and how it also applies to the builtin `Object` and `Function` hierarchies, [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=constructor+object+property+inherit*+code%3A"Function.prototype").